# Tensorflow cannot get gradient wrt a Variable, but can wrt a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

I am interested in computing the gradient of a loss that is calculated from a product of a matrix multiplication in TensorFlow with Eager Execution. I can do so if the product is computed as a tensor, but not if it's `assign()`ed in place to a variable. Here is the *greatly* reduced code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.enable_eager_execution()

multipliers_net = tf.get_variable("multipliers", shape=(1, 3, 3, 1),
                                  initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
activations_net = tf.Variable(tf.ones_like(multipliers_net))
output_indices = [(0, 1, 2, 0)]

def step():
    global activations_net

    #### PROBLEMATIC ####
    activations_net.assign(multipliers_net * activations_net)
    #### NO PROBLEM ####
    # activations_net = multipliers_net * activations_net

    return tf.gather_nd(activations_net, output_indices)


def train(targets):
    for y in targets:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            out = step()
            print("OUT", out)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - out))
            print("LOSS", loss)
        de_dm = tape.gradient(loss, multipliers_net)
        print("GRADIENT", de_dm, sep="\n")
        multipliers_net.assign(LEARNING_RATE * de_dm)


targets = [[2], [3], [4], [5]]

train(targets)
```

As it stands, this code will show the correct OUT and LOSS values, **but the GRADIENT will be printed as None**. However, if the line below "PROBLEMATIC" is commented and the "NO PROBLEM" is uncommented, the gradient is computed just fine. I infer this is because in the second case, `activations_net` becomes a Tensor, but I don't know why that suddenly makes the gradient computable, whereas before it was not.

I'm pretty sure that I should keep `activations_net` and `multiplier_net` as Variables, because in the larger scheme of things, both are updated dynamically and as I understand it, such things are best kept as Variables instead of constantly reassigning Tensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain to the best of my knowledge. 
The problem occurs in a this line

```
de_dm = tape.gradient(loss, multipliers_net)
```

If you `print(tape.watched_variables()` in both "PROBLEMATIC" and "NO PROBLEM" cases, you'll see that in first case tape 'watches' the same `multipliers_net` variable twice. 
You can try `tape.reset()` and `tape.watch()`, but it will have no effect as long as you pass assign op into it.
If you try `multipliers_net.assign(any_variable)` inside `tf.GradientTape()`, you'll find that it won't work. But if you try assigning something that produces tensor, e.g. `tf.ones_like()`, it will work.

```
multipliers_net.assign(LEARNING_RATE * de_dm)
```

This works for same reason. It seems to accept only `eager_tensors`
Hope this helps

Comment: It seems that the `assign` op has no gradient, no matter what you're assigning...

Comment: Yes. I actually a little confused its behaviour, especially eager.Variable.assign, which should work but it doesn't. So does read_value parameter

Comment: but i think as long as you do `multipliers_net.assign` you get a resourceVariable which is what you want

Comment: @IvanVegner i think the answer to your question is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17735